# PHP SoapClient over selfsigned certificate, SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://

Tags: php, soap, https, certificate, self-signed

I browsed the net for three days and I still can not solve my problem... That's why I ask for your help :)

I try to call a web servcice over https with selfsigned certificate and i get the following error : SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://...

My code :

```
$streamContext = stream_context_create(array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
     )
));
$client = new SoapClient("https://DOMAIN/ws.php?wsdl", array(
    'trace' => true,
    'stream_context' => $streamContext
));
$client->method($params);
```

I tried to :

- Change values of "verify_peer" and "allow_self_signed" options ;
- Replace "ssl" key by "https" in stream_context array ;
- Load the WSDL file locally but i get the following error : Could not connect to host (my endpoint : https://DOMAIN/ws.php);
- Clear my client cache ;
- Use Zend_Soap_Client and nusoap library.

Also, I checked the connection between the client and the server with the following commands "ping DOMAIN" and "telnet DOMAIN 443" and everything is ok.

It seems the "stream_context" option is ignored or the problem is elsewhere ?!
Is it a php Bug ?!

All suggestions will be appreciated.
Thx

Comment: Can you open an https://DOMAIN/ws.php?wsdl url with your browser? Or WGET on a server where php runs? Is your web server configured properly ? It must not only listen to connections on port 443 but also have proper settings regarding server certificate etc.

Comment: Hi Greg, I can open the WSDL with my browser when i bypass the security (NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID). I can download the WSDL with a wget command on my php server only with this option "no-check-certificate". Unfortunately, I do not have hands to set or check the web server settings...

Comment: There is a note in php manual: 
Underlying socket stream context options
Additional context options may be supported by the underlying transport For http:// streams, refer to context options for the tcp:// transport. For https:// streams, refer to context options for the ssl:// transport.

You are using http:// and https:// in your xml so try to set context options for https also.

Comment: Hi Greg, Thx for your comment. I tried to replace "ssl" key by : "https" and "http", unfortunately i've got the same error...

Comment: Can you post your wsdl file ?

Comment: I think no, it's a very big file (nearly 40 MB) and I'm still front the same problem when I try to reduce the contents of the WSDL.

Answer (score 3):

I had a very similar problem and I added `'verify_peer_name' => false` to the stream context. So...

```php
$streamContext = stream_context_create(array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
     )
));
```

> ***Editor's note***: disabling SSL verification has **security implications.** Without verification of the authenticity of SSL/HTTPS connections, a malicious attacker can impersonate a trusted endpoint (such as GitHub or some other remote Git host), and you'll be vulnerable to a [Man-in-the-Middle Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack). **Be sure you fully understand the security issues before using this as a solution.**